# Using rosbag with rosjava

Tags: rosbag, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm using the latest software for java and rosjava and after searching for a few hours, I couldn't find any api information on how to use rosbag from rosjava. Specifically, writing and reading to and from a bag file. Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Blair

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38903/using-rosbag-with-rosjava/) by [bgagnon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2657/bgagnon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosjava doesn't provide that functionality. However, the rosbag file format is documented [here](http://ros.org/wiki/Bags/Format) so it shouldn't be too hard to implement a rosbag java library.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0